# Finding values index wise

Tags: python, numpy

I have to perform RMSE on two columns with different Non-Nan values.
I have found the indices of Non-Nan Values in the first column. Now I have filtered out the values of 2nd column according to those indices.

This is the code I used to find the values of indices:-

```
b = np.argwhere(y.notnull().values).tolist()
```

Here y is the column which stores the indices of Non-Nan values in b.
I have another column x and have to match b with values of x. Filter out those values and store it in another column.

Comment: Are you using pandas dataframes?

Comment: Use `df.dropna(inplace=True)` and perform your operation.

Comment: according to your code b should be storing indices of not null values of y but your question states otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas dataframes, you can use pandas iloc

```
df[x].iloc[b]
```

You can just get the values using the values attribute

```
df[x].iloc[b].values
```

Answer (score 0):

OR if wanted a list do:

```
print(df[column].iloc[b].values.tolist())
```